# Having issues while running bootstrap validator along with ajax

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, forms, validation, bootstrapvalidator

I have a signup form on which i wish to apply [bootstrap validator](http://1000hz.github.io/bootstrap-validator/)  and if the form is filled successfully it should go to the ajax part where the backend script will run and data gets submitted.

Form

```
<form data-toggle="validator" role="form"  id="signup-form" method="post">

    <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" name="cname" id="cname" required>

    <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control" placeholder=" email" name="email" data-error="email address is invalid" required>

     <input type="password" class="form-control out-box" placeholder="Password" name="password" id="password" required>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit_form">SIGN UP</button>

</form>
```

Ajax Code

```
$("#submit_form").click(function()
  {
    var cname = $("#cname").val();
    var email = $("#email").val();
    var password = $("#password").val();
    var dataString = 'cname='+ cname + '&email='+ email + '&password='+ password ;

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>/student/register",
      data: dataString,
      cache: false,
      success: function(result){
        console.log(result);     
    }});
    return false;
  });
```

Issue is that, if the form is empty or has any issues and i hit submit button, the problematic area gets highlighted as it haapens in bootstrap validator, but after that ajax code is also executed.

I want that the ajax code should only run when all the validations are fullfilled and the form has no issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following way.

```
$('#signup-form').validator().on('submit', function (e) {
  if (e.isDefaultPrevented()) {
    // handle the invalid form...
  } else {
    // everything looks good!
     var cname = $("#cname").val();
    var email = $("#email").val();
    var password = $("#password").val();
    var dataString = 'cname='+ cname + '&email='+ email + '&password='+ password ;

    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>/student/register",
      data: dataString,
      cache: false,
      success: function(result){
        console.log(result);     
    }});
    return false;
  }
})
```